# Where on the OSX Mavericks is the Applications folder supposed to be?

Tags: macos

All my Music, Movies, Documents etc, are stored under /Users/myusername/

But it seems that Applications are stored under:   /Macintosh HD/Applications

Is there something wrong with my installation ? Is it supposed to be there ? I don't recall moving the applications folder there. It just seems weird that it isn't stored in my user directory.

Could parallels have done this?

Comment: This is regular.

Comment: A user will have access two applications folder, one shared one under `/Applications` and another under `~/Applications`, the latter is for private apps. Parallels however, would create a custom folder in your home folder when you share applications between your VM and OS X. It will be named like `~/Applications(Windows)` in which fake apps that link to the actual Windows app is created. There's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong. That is how your Apple is suppose to be. /Applications , /Library , and /System are managed and used primarily by the OS. Your files should be in your user folder /Users/john for example. If you want you can create another folder in your home folder (user folder) called Applications or Programs or "whatever" and put third party apps in there. It is your choice but you shouldn't remove any applications from the /Application folder should they automatically be installed there or be default programs, doing so will result in issues.

Comment: Actually, I believe, there is already a folder in your home directory called ~/Applications. Basically just apps for your exclusive use that other users don't have access to. I've never used it nor had a need to do so, but like Andrew said, your Applications folder IS in the right place.

Comment: Sorry Steve but that folder is not default. It might show up after installing third party programs (such as Adobe programs). This can be verified by creating a new test user on your computer (standard or admin) and you will see that it creates only a certain list of folders therein, none of which are an "Application" folder.

Comment: ...when I make a new test user, there is an Applications folder in my home directory, as Steve describes. It's been that way for as long as I've used OS X (~2010ish)